# Access--I need a list of dynamic check boxes on a form

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a form in Access which will have a dynamic list of check boxes. It starts with a table tblMASTER_ATTACHMENT_LIST which will have three columns: MASTER_ATTACHMENT_ID, CLASS, and ATTACHMENT_NAME. (Before I go any further, this question is not about file attachments. Think more along the lines of an attachment to a report.) tblMASTER_ATTACHMENTS will be "pre-populated" with all possible reports and their classification. There will be another table tblREPORT_ATTACHMENTS, which will have the following columns: ID, REPORT_ID, MASTER_ATTACHMENT_ID, and ATTACHED_BL (boolean). So, depending on the class of the report, the list of possible attachments may change. I would like the list of possible attachments to be populated on a form, with check boxes next to each one to show whether it was actually attached or not.

I was thinking about a workflow such as once a user selects the class of report, to delete any records in the tblREPORT_ATTACHMENTS with the REPORT_ID equal to the current RECORD_ID, and then fill the form control with the results of SELECTing the records from the master table where CLASS = selected class.

If this workflow makes sense, I could use some help implementing it. Specifically, how do I build the control on the form that will hold the check boxes? If this workflow is not a very smart way to do, can someone suggest a better way? And explain how to do it?

By the way, I did search for this, but I don't really know what this type of thing is called. Makes it pretty hard to search for. If this is a common thing, perhaps someone could just point me in the right direction. In that case, a full answer here would not be necessary.

Comment: Where a list is variable, it is nearly always best to use a subform. Add control dynamically is rarely a good idea in MS access.

Comment: Yes, I did know it would be on a sub form. Do you have any suggestions about how to go about it?

Comment: Set the contents of the subform from the master attachment list according to the relevance to the report. I would probably use a junction table and set the child and master fields.

Comment: I agree that many-to-many with a junction table is probably a good way to go. Is it considered bad form to put other columns in the junction table? Namely, a boolean to indicate whether the attachment was used? Or is it best to only have entries for attachments that were used and the presence of the entry indicates such and the absence of an entry indicates it was not used? In which case, I wonder about the user interface. How will I present the complete list and provide check boxes to indicate which attachments were used?

Comment: If you want a checkbox, you may as well use tblREPORT_ATTACHMENTS in the subform. the point of the junction table was that you would just add attachments to the subform as they were found, so the junction table would only contain the used attachments. So Master = all attachments, Report = possible attachments by report type, Junction = Actual attachments for this report.